# Perform Calculation based on multi-criteria matching and lookup value

Tags: if-statement, indexing, match

I'm trying to calculate the amount over a daily meal reimbursement rate IFF all meals on a given day were personal meals (i.e. the individual didn't buy someone else's meal). In the attached example, all meals being personal meals would include blanks or a "No" in the "Group Expense" column. If they selected a "Yes" for either breakfast or lunch or dinner, no calculation would be performed.

For example, the total spent on meals in the example is $83.79. The daily limit is $70. If these meals were all personal (i.e. a blank/no response was provided in the Group Expense column), $13.79 would be returned in the highlighted cell (K6). If they selected a "Yes" for either breakfast or lunch or dinner (or any combination thereof) $0 (or blank) would display in the highlighted cell (K6).

Thus far I've been trying to combine IF statements, with OR statements, with Index/Match using multiple criteria.

I've tried to match expense totals between the "input area" and "summary area" (the summary area is populated from the input area using index/match already), then match the dates between input area and summary area, then match the meal type between input area and summary area, and then look for any "Yes" responses in the input area. If ANY YES responses exist (hence my attempt at incorporating an OR statement), DO NOT show any amount over the daily $70 rate; otherwise calculate the excess.

Examples of some of the formulas I've tried are shown in the attached.

I would appreciate some expert advice!

Thanks,

A

[image: Example Problem]

Comment: The following will get me the correct answer: {=IF(OR(S6:S8={"Yes"}),0,SUM(K3:K5)-R11)}. If "Yes" is selected for either breakfast, lunch, or dinner (obviously I specifically selected the cells I needed to test it), zero is returned, otherwise it performs the calculation I want. However, I'm still having issues incorporating it with INDEX/MATCH so it is a dynamic formula that it calculates based on the specific "Date" and "Expense Detail" type. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it.

Essentially I replaced the "S6:S8" portion of the test formula above [*{=IF(OR(S6:S8={"Yes"}),0,SUM(K3:K5)-R11)}*] with an index/match argument.

S6:S8={"Yes"} within the OR statement becomes *INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$3,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes"*. This is repeated for each meal criteria type (tried using D3&***H3:H5*** but it would only recognize the result in H3).

The following is what works for me:

{=IF(OR(INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$3,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$4,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$5,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes"),0,SUM($K$3:$K$5)-$R$11)}

Now if a "Yes" is selected for either breakfast, lunch, or dinner on the input table, zero is returned, otherwise it performs the "overage" calculation I was after.

Comment: Caught an error in my logic. If there is no breakfast, for example, the index/match will return an error. To account for potential blanks on the input tab, I had to return a zero at each index/match error and then adjust the "value if false" formula to eliminate it calculating a negative amount (i.e. the index match found no "Yes, "No" or "" responses so it moved to the "value if false" calculation which subtracted $70 from $0). This formula works:

Comment: _{=IF(OR(IFERROR(INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$3,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",0),IFERROR(INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$4,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",0),IFERROR(INDEX(InputTable[Group Expense],MATCH($D$3&$H$5,InputTable[Date]&InputTable[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",0)),0,IF((SUM($K$3:$K$5)-$R$11)<0,0,SUM($K$3:$K$5)-$R$11))}_

Comment: Sorry for the "multiple" answers. But I caught a second error in the revised solution immediately above. The final IF statement was not appropriately dealing with both blank selections and non-blank selections for meal type AND dealing with the "Group Expense" vs. "Non-Group Expense" (i.e. if they had a group expense they could exceed the $70 cap, otherwise they were capped at $70). The formula below should now deal with all situations appropriately (I've tested every scenario I could think of):

Comment: {=IF(OR(IFERROR(INDEX(TravelLogInput[Group Expense],MATCH('Test Worksheet'!$D$53&'Test Worksheet'!$H$53,TravelLogInput[Date]&TravelLogInput[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",0),
IFERROR(INDEX(TravelLogInput[Group Expense],MATCH('Test Worksheet'!$D$53&'Test Worksheet'!$H$54,TravelLogInput[Date]&TravelLogInput[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",0),
IFERROR(INDEX(TravelLogInput[Group Expense],MATCH('Test Worksheet'!$D$53&'Test Worksheet'!$H$55,TravelLogInput[Date]&TravelLogInput[Expense Detail],0))="Yes",0)),
0,MAX(0,SUM('Test Worksheet'!$K$53:$K$55)-'Annual Data Inputs'!$E$5))}